# Android: StackOverFlowError with InvocationTargetException when inflating layout

Tags: android, android-layout

First, sorry for my English. I have a question when inflating layout:

I have a custom view, extends from a LinearLayout, called **ButtonHelp**. I use that view on my layout named **LoadingActivity**. My below codes work perfectly on every devices and emulators, except ones with QVGA screen like Samsung Galaxy Y with following errors:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.LoadingActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class com.myapp.customviews.ButtonHelp  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)  
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class com.myapp.customviews.ButtonHelp
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
    at com.myapp.LoadingActivity.onCreate(LoadingActivity.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.myapp.customviews.ButtonHelp.initLayout(ButtonHelp.java:29)
    at com.myapp.customviews.ButtonHelp.<init>(ButtonHelp.java:17)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at android.util.LongSparseArray.get(LongSparseArray.java:79)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getCachedDrawable(Resources.java:1746)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1664)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.
```

The problem is, I have no idea about this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at android.util.LongSparseArray.get(LongSparseArray.java:79)
```

Why does it happen on QVGA emulators/devices?

FYI:

- I have image resources for screen 320x480 only.
- **ButtonHelp** layout:

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/btnhelp_help"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:background="@drawable/loading_button_help"
      android:src="@drawable/loading_icon_help" />
  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- **ButtonHelp** code:

  ```
  public class ButtonHelp extends LinearLayout {
      private ImageButton mHelp;

      public ButtonHelp(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
          initLayout();
          initControls();
      }

      public ButtonHelp(Context context) {
          super(context);
          initLayout();
          initControls();
      }

      private void initLayout() {
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          inflater.inflate(R.layout.btn_help, this);
      }

      private void initControls() {
          mHelp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnhelp_help);
      }

      public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
          mHelp.setOnClickListener(listener);
      }
  }
  ```
- **ButtonHelp** is used in **LoadingActivity**:

  ```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/loading_background"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

  ...

      <com.myapp.customviews.ButtonHelp
          android:id="@+id/loading_help"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

  ...

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- When I remove **ButtonHelp**, the error still appears when creating layout, just like above logcat.

I've searched another SO questions but still have no solution or explanation for this case.

Many thanks!

---

## UPDATE:

As asked, below are codes for `loading_button_help`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loading_button_help" /> <!-- Normal -->

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loading_button_help" /> <!--  Normal disable -->

    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/loading_button_help_press" /> <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loading_button_help" /> <!-- selected -->

    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loading_button_help" /> <!-- normal -->

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loading_button_help" /> <!-- normal disable focused -->

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/loading_button_help" /> <!-- normal disable -->
</selector>
```

And `loading_icon_help` is just a PNG image.

Comment: What are `loading_button_help` and `loading_icon_help` drawables?

Comment: @a.ch. `loading_button_help`: is a drawable xml defines button states, and `loading_icon_help` is an image drawable.

Comment: Could you provide their xmls?

Comment: @a.ch. I've updated them in the question body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In loading_button_help.xml you use @drawable/loading_button_help? I think you have cyclic reference. Try to rename your xml or image file.

Comment: Thank you @appserv. My bad, don't know why i don't notice it at the first time.